Is there another way of deriving the Fourier transform of 1?
Reasoning with generalized functions we can derive that the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta function is:
$$\langle \mathcal{F}[\delta(x)](p),\phi(p) \rangle=\langle \delta(x),\mathcal{F}[\phi(p)](x) \rangle=\mathcal{F}[\phi](0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ip0}\phi(p)dp=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1\cdot\phi(p)dp=\langle 1,\phi(p) \rangle\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[\delta(x)]=1$$
So now the standard procedure is to conclude that the inverse transform of $1$ i $\delta(x)$:
$$\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}^{-1}[1](x)=\delta(x)$$
However I'm wondering if it is possible to reason like in the beggining:
$$\langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}[1](x), \phi(x)\rangle=\langle1, \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\phi(x)](p)\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ipx}\phi(x)dx \ dp=\cdot\cdot\cdot=\phi(0)=\langle\delta(x),\phi(x)\rangle\\$$
Is there a way to prove that this double integral in fact gives you $\phi(0)$ or is it that the only way to reason about the Fourier transform of $1$ is through the fourier transform of $\delta(x)$?

That's the essence of the Fourier inversion theorem. You usually regularise the delta by a Gaussian for which you can compute everything analytically.

Yes, we can derive the inverse Fourier Transform of $1$ using the approach you outlined. First, we let $F(k)=1$.  Then, we have for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$,
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F^{-1}}\{F\},\phi\rangle&=\langle 1,\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-L}^L \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\,dk\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{Fubini}} \lim_{L\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\int_{-L}^L e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) \frac{2\sin(Lx)}{x}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$
Now, we integrate by parts with $u=\phi$ and $v=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{2\sin(Lt)}{t}\,dt$.  Proceeding, we find that
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F^{-1}}\{F\},\phi\rangle&=-\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{2\sin(Lt)}{t}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(t)}{t}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{DCT}}-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(t)}{t}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) 2\pi H(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) \,dx\\\\
&=\phi(0)
\end{align}$$
Therefore, in distribution we have
$$\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{1\}(x)=\delta(x)$$

Where did the Heaviside function come from at the end?

When $x<0$, $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(t)}{t},dt=0$.  When $x>0$, $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(t)}{t},dt=2\pi$.

Oh of course. Thanks a lot that is an amazing proof!

@KrumKutsarov You're welcome.  My pleasure.

DCT is direct comparison test?

It looks to me, at the moment, as if there's an extraneous $\lim_{L\to\infty}$ in the third line of the second set of displayed equations.

@Aruralreader "DCT" is an acronym for "Dominated Convergence Theorem."  The DCT guarantees that the interchange of the limit and integral is legitimate.  And thank you for catching the extraneous limit.  I've edited accordingly.

@MarkViola, thank you kindly for the explanation, that little bit helps me considerably. And thank you for sharing such a clean, instructive solution.

@Aruralreader You're quite welcome.  Thank you for the nice note.  And pleased to hear that this solution helped!
